# "Framing not allowed" when re-opening closed tab in google chrome

Tags: bug

Apparently framing is not allowed.  I presume this means loading stackexchange in an iframe.  However I recently started seeing that error message from stackexchange when I closed a security.stackexchange tab and then re-opened it using google chrome (they have a specific action for "reopen last closed tab").  The strange part is that I only see this happen on security.stackexchange.com.  It doesn't happen on stackoverflow.com.  It happens both on question pages and the security.stackexchange.com homepage.

At first I was going to dismiss it as a browser quirk (I'm on a slightly old version of chrome), but given that it only happens on security.stackexchange.com, I'm guessing it's not my browser (or not *just* my browser).

If this is a bug, it obviously this isn't the highest priority, but I thought I would mention it.

Comment: You may want to bring this up on [meta.se], since no one on this specific Meta has the ability to modify the actual Stack Exchange website design.